# Is derivative function a discontinued function as the limit says as h tends to 0 and nothing can be divided by 0?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

What does really the rate of change in function mean here; the real function must be like $\frac {F(x+h) - F(x) } h$ and not $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac {F(x+h) - F(x) } h$

Comment: The limit can exist, although we cannot divide by $0$, and if it exists , it is called the derivate of $F$ at $x_0=x$

Comment: Limits are not the same thing as direct substitution in general. The expression $((x+h)^2-x^2)/h$ is not continuous at $0$ *as a function of* $h$ since it is not even defined at $h=0$, but it has a limit $2x$ as $h$ tends to 0. When we speak about a derivative $f'(x)$ being continuous or not, we mean continuity of the derivative (that limit in $h$) as a function of $x$. The limit is taken in $h$ and we want to know if that limit is a continuous function of the original function variable $x$.

Comment: Could you edit the title of the question since it's not clear?

Comment: You need parentheses to have $F(x+h)$ in the numerator.